# What is the zero index in getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname

Could someone tell, what happens when using this zero index?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Note: A much easier way to reference the `<head>` element is just [`document.head`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/head).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'myscript.js';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
```

You get all head elements **(there should be only one)** and you add the script there so the result is

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    ...
```

if there's no head in the document, most browsers will create the head element even if the tag is not there.

Have a look at this, it might can help.
http://www.jspatterns.com/the-ridiculous-case-of-adding-a-script-element/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The function [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) will return an array-like HTMLCollection object and when you access this object with index zero, it will give you the first entry of that data structure.

Indexes start at zero in JavaScript (as in many programming languages).

Answer (score 1):

The  [**getElementsByTagName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a live HTMLCollection of elements with the given tag name.The `HTMLCollection` interface represents a array-like object of elements.

Hence passing zero will give the element in the first `index` that is zeroth index

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
console.log(elements);
console.log(elements[0]) // <div> First </div>
```

```html
<div> First </div>
<div> Second </div>
<div> Third </div>
<div> Fourth </div>
```